# Consulta MySQL muestra datos erróneos

Tags: mysql

tengo la siguiente base de datos:

[image: Modelo entidad-relación]

Y tengo que hacer la siguiente actividad:

**Listar   los   números   de   clientes   asignados   a   Viguer   Sánchez,

Antonio  que  al menos  hayan  hecho  un  pedido  superior  a 30000.**

*He hecho la siguiente consulta:*

```
select e.nombre, count(*) total
from cliente c
join pedido on cliente = NUM_CLIE
join empleado e on numemp = repclie
where NUMPEDIDO in (select numpedido
                    from lineaspedido
                    group by 1
                    having sum(importe) > 100) and
      e.nombre = "Miguel Moreno"
group by 1;
```

El problema es que me da 3 el conteo cuando el empleado solo tiene a dos clientes que cumplan esa condición asignada. Creo que lo que está pasando es que la subselect me devuelve varios números de pedidos y que el cliente uno, cumple la condición dos veces, así que se muestra repetido de ahí que haya uno extra.

¿cómo podría arreglar la consulta?

PD: la base de datos y el ejercicio no tienen sentido del todo, pero son ejercicios de clases, no le presteis mayor atención a eso, por favor.

Comment: No entiendo, en tu enunciado dices un pedido mayor a 3000 pero en tu consulta solo pones mayor a 100

Comment: Como he dicho, es un ejercicio de clase. En mi base de datos no tengo un cliente que cumplan esa condición, así que he modificado el número para que me saliera algún dato.

Tendré más cuidado la próxima y pondré los datos correctamente.

Gracias.

Comment: Tu consulta está escrita de una forma confusa, una extraña mezcla de joins explícitos e implícitos y unos `group by 1` que no son habituales hasta donde yo conozco. Intenta de este modo y dime si funciona o qué ocurre: `SELECT e.nombre, COUNT(*) total
FROM empleado e 
INNER JOIN cliente c ON e.NumEmp = c.REPCLIE
INNER JOIN pedido  p ON p.CLIENTE = c.NUM_CLIE
WHERE 
 p.NUMPEDIDO IN (SELECT NUMPEDIDO
                          FROM lineaspedido
                      GROUP BY NUMPEDIDO
                      HAVING SUM(importe) > 100)
    AND e.nombre = "Miguel Moreno"
GROUP BY e.nombre;`

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, @A.Cedano, ¿Qué puedo decir? Ni siquiera me dejan poner inner join, me obligan a poner join, y muchas otras cosas como que no puedo poner alias y que no tengo ni idea de cómo funciona una subselect por dentro y tal y tal... Lo que tienen los profesores, en fin...

En tu consulta pasa lo mismo que en la mía. Me devuelve 3, en lugar de dos. Lo he solucionado poniendo distinct num_clie dentro del count.

Si sabéis de algún tutorial donde aprender bien sql, lo agradecería.

Comment: Realmente `INNER JOIN`  y `JOIN` es lo mismo. En ese caso, en lugar del `DISTINCT` quizá podrías agrupar por `num_clie`, algo así: `... AND e.nombre = "Miguel Moreno" GROUP BY e.nombre, c.NUM_CLIE` Creo que así debería funcionar y podrías dejar  el `COUNT(*)`  tal cual.

Comment: De nuevo, gracias por la ayuda, pero tampoco funciona.

En ese caso, salen dos filas, una por cada empleado.

Comment: Para mí es difícil entender el contexto sin ver un dataset. Es extraño que tengas que recurrir a un `DISTINCT` en el `COUNT()`. Además, leyendo de nuevo el enunciado no tendría sentido hacer eso, porque se quiere contar precisamente cuantos clientes de ese empleando cumplen el criterio. Sería interesante ver el resultado de la subquery uniéndola con la  tabla `pedido` y sin el `HAVING` para ver cuál es la realidad de los datos. A veces hay errores en ellos.

Comment: @A.Cedano, no entiendo bien tu mensaje. Bueno, la consulta me funciona, no sé si me funcionará cambiando al empleado, pero creo que sí.

La base de datos es un desastre y no te digo nada de los datos... Está hecho así "aposta". 

En fin, seguiré posteando dudas, que tengo varias y agradecería la ayuda que pudiérais brindarme. Y la mento que la base de datos sea tan desastrosa. Es la que nos dieron y sobre la que tenemos que trabajar.

Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Me refería a simplificar la consulta, para revisar los resultados. Eso ayuda mucho cuando tienes bases de datos desastrosas como parece ser el caso . Por ejemplo podrías empezar con los pedidos de un empleado `X` agrupados, luego agrupas por clientes, luego sumas, etc y así vas viendo cómo están los datos realmente.

Comment: @A.Cedano, todo ese proceso ya lo hice. Intento ir poco a poco haciendo las consultas. Realmente el problema es que al unir clientes con pedidos y pedidos con líneaspedido, hay 2 clientes que cumplen la condición, pero el cliente 1 tiene dos pedidos que cumplen la condición, así que sale 2 veces, dándome un total de 3, cuando solo quiero que salgan los clientes como tal y no el número de pedidos que cumple dicha condición. No sé si me he explicado. Gracias por la ayuda prestada :).

Comment: No sé, me parece entonces que el modelo de datos no está normalizado realmente. Yo no soy experto en diagramas como el que muestras, yo trabajo viendo los datos en sí. O quizá sea cuestión de plantear la consulta de otra manera. El hecho es que no me quedo conforme con lo del `DISTINCT` en el `COUNT()`.